# Get Proguard mapping files from bundle

Tags: android, google-play, bundle, proguard

How can I get the Proguard mapping files for the APKs created, and signed, by the Play Store from an uploaded bundle? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play store doesn't generate a new mapping file.
If you obfuscate your code and upload bundle, it's the same mapping file. 
The bundle can be downloaded from `App bundle explorer` and the mapping file is in `BUNDLE-METADATA/com.android.tools.build.obfuscation`.

Comment: I don't see any download button related to mapping file. You can delete it only? Or do you mean it is contained inside an apk?